# Browser Add-on development to convert Youtube WL to playlist

Tags: browser, youtube, add-on, playlist

I need some advice on how to start developing an add-on for a browser. I want to implement something into Youtube that accesses a user's profile in order to get to their playlists. I'm not looking for an add-on that helps to develop things, but to directly program an add-on itself, but I'm not sure where to get started. Any advice is appreciated, thanks!